# How to setup a Kendo UI grid with a dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, grid, kendo-ui

Before proceeding to this community to ask my question, I have thoroughly searched google, bing, and also the Kendo UI documentation for information and seem to get nothing like I want.

I want to setup a grid(a strongly typed one) with one of its columns bound to a property of **List** type on the model. This column should display this property in a dropdownlist. This is where the problem lies.

All the examples I have seen always used a viewdata type to hold the data of IEnumerable type.
Can some one show me how to set this up  plus I find the ClientTemplate method so confusing in this respect.

I'm a newbie to Kendo UI btw.

Thanks.

Comment: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html   Just change the viewdata to the list in your model

Comment: @NunoCarmo, thanks for your response. However, using the `columns.ForeignKey()` method means passing in the property in my model that represents the foreign key but isn't doable per se as I have represented a reference to the other model as a **LIST** of that type.
That's why I ask is there another way?

Comment: First of all do you want to: DISPLAY DropDownList (without editing the row) or you want to EDIT the field via a DropDownList. Because client template is Display template and ForeignKey is Editor Template ?

Comment: @Pechka, I want to be able to do both!

Comment: Oswald your response to NunoCarmo confused me a bit...please could you include a definition of what your model is (the one you are binding to the grid) and also the definition of the model that should be bound to your dropdownlist.